# Compute variance via functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming

So I'm supposed to calculate variance based on this forumula through functional programming:

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} (X -\mu)^2}{n-1}$$

This is the code that works:

```
public static double variance1(int[] array)
{
     double mean=mean(array);
     double summation=DoubleStream.iterate(0,idx->idx+1)
                                  .limit(array.length)
                                  .reduce(0,(summation_counter,idx)->
                                   {
                                     return Math.pow(array[(int)idx]-mean, 2)+summation_counter;
                                   });
                                  
                               
     return summation/(array.length-1);
}
```

Although the code works, it's ugly with the typecasts and seems forced.

Initially, I thought of doing something like

```
double summation=IntStream.rangeClosed(0,array.length-1)
                          .reduce(0, (summation_counter,idx)-> ....
```

but I couldn't use an `IntStream` as the body of the `reduce` method returns double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, watch your formating. Java standard is to have spaces around operators, and a space after commas. In the `reduce` lambda you can leave out the `return` and the braces, just like you did't for `iterate`.

It's a bit ugly to use a `DoubleStream` for the array indices, and number streams provide a `sum()` method, so using reduce is unnecessary.

An array can easily streamed using `Arrays.stream()`, which produces an `IntStream` and  with `mapToDouble` a `DoubleStream` can be created:

```
double summation = Arrays.stream(array)
                     .mapToDouble(x -> (x - mean) * (x - mean))
                     .sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there's no other way to return a double with the `reduce` and have an int value as the index without casting; it's either integer or double.

For the rest of the code, here is some advice.

#### Add checks for empty / null on the array.

In my opinion, it's always a good thing to verify the validity of the `array` parameter before handling it (not null, and have at least one element in this case).

#### Use the multiplication operator instead of `Math.Pow`

The `Math.Pow` tend to be slower in some case when compared with the multiplication operator.
In my opinion, it's best to use the multiplication operator when the `exponent < 5`.

Comment: Do you think using `Optional<Double>` or `null` checking on the array is better?

Comment: To clarify, I was talking of adding a condition that check if the `array` parameter is valid (not null & size > 0); this condition should be before the call of the method `mean`.

This condition will prevent invalid parameters of reaching your code.